# After marcotting Mango, Chico, and Duhat, when will the roots appear?

Tags: fruit-trees, propagation, tropical, air-layer, mango

We are planning to marcot Mango, Chico and Duhat.

Approximately how many days after marcotting each of these respective plants will the roots begin to appear?

We ask because we live in the <s>equatorial region</s>Philippines, and we would like to do it right the first time.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layering#Air_layering):

> It can take the layer from a few weeks to one or more growing seasons to produce sufficient roots; this is largely dependent on the plant species and the vigor of the parent plant.

**Edit (September 2, 2020)** Daytime temperature in our place ranges from 34 degrees to 38 degrees Celsius.  Nighttime temperature ranges from 28 to 33 degrees Celsius.  It is very humid here.  There is the Laguna Lake nearby (so would that qualify for maritime climate?).  About the particular Mango species to be marcotted, I am not particularly sure about the scientific name, but I am attaching herewith a photo of said (ripe) Mango:
[image]

We are still uncertain about the following:

- diameter & ages of branches intended; and
- specific air layering methods intended

Are there prescribed procedures/methods for these, with the background information that I have given so far?

Comment: Good question; if could include a more specific equatorial region, intended species of Mango Tree, average daytime temperatures, average night time temperatures, average humidity, if a maritime climate, diameter & ages of branches intended, and specific air layering methods intended, could be helpful, since the different trees may have different rooting characteristics and different growth rates. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you for the tips, @MH.  I will consult with my uncle, as he was the one who instructed me to inquire for this information.

Comment: You are very welcome; very small differences can have significant effects on results. Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Comment: You are very welcome; very small differences can have significant effects on results; all three Trees should airlayer well there; tropical tree marcotting methods in tropical maritime regions differ some from marcotting methods in other regions, and the area around Laguna Lake is maritime; very helpful illustration & additional material. Thank you! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best time to marcot your mango trees is when they are producing new leaves. I don't think you have a proper spring as such where you are, which is when marcotting would be done in the northern hemisphere, but even so, you may get faster rooting earlier in the year than you will now. However, you will obviously know when your tree is producing new leaves and is in active growth, so try whenever that is happening. Although this really applies to marcotting in more temperate zones, there is general guidance on this procedure here which should be helpful to you
https://homeguides.sfgate.com/right-time-year-air-layer-deciduous-tree-47240.html.

Length of time for roots to be produced is usually 2-3 months, but it does vary depending on conditions.  In terms of selecting the right size stem and having a visual step by step guide to the procedure, there are many Youtube videos on line which you should be able to access by googlig 'marcotting a mango tree', but here is a link to one example https://youtu.be/P_XSFtP3atk